# НЕ могу понять ошибку в написании триггера mysql

Tags: mysql

При добавлении новой строки в таблицу выскакивает ошибка 
    ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'parts' in stored function/trigger 
    because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored 
    function/trigger.

```
CREATE 
    DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
TRIGGER `60541_arr`.trigger1
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON `60541_arr`.parts
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE N int DEFAULT 0;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO N FROM parts WHERE Part_name=NEW.Part_name;
  IF N > 0 THEN 
    UPDATE parts SET Part_name =CONCAT(Part_name,'-',N);
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Триггер не может выполнять update той таблицы, на которую написан. Кроме того в вашем UPDATE нет части WHERE в итоге он изменит значение во всех записях таблицы и по этой же причине совершенно не ясно, что он должен делать. Если вам надо изменить значение поля _текущей_ записи, то выполните `set NEW.Part_name = новое_значение`

Comment: Исправил, теперь все вводит. Подскажите пожалуйста как теперь изменять так, чтоб измененные детали тоже считались.

Comment: Например, я создал деталь, затем еще одну и у нее становиться имя деталь-1, и дальше при новых созданных будет деталь-1, как их праавильно считать?

Comment: берите например `max(part_name)`, но имейте ввиду, что `деталь-2` больше чем `деталь-11`. И по хорошему нужно отдельное числовое поле. Либо имена делать с ведущими нулями `деталь-001`, `деталь-021`